# Ethernet port broken and need to install from network

Tags: usb, ethernet

In one of my laptops, the Ethernet port is broken and I need to reinstall Windows from the company's network.

Will any USB-Ethernet adapter work fine in this particular situation?

Comment: Yeah it should work just fine.

Comment: Just a caveat, some USB Ethernet may need driver that the OS may not have... so hopefully whatever you have will not need additional driver and just works right off the bat.

Comment: "from the company's network".. that sounds as if you are in a company. And those typical hand out the same type of laptop to every user. So IT should be able to swap your SSD/HDD into another laptop, PXE-image it, and swap back top your identical laptop.

Comment: @hennes that is not an option :)

Comment: Then all I have are either "be very lucky with an USB based Ethernet solution" or "Boot from something else (CD, USB pendrive, ...), have that have the drivers for some kind of network and start the install from there. ... Or replace the broken Ethernet port. Simplest solution, often within warranty (companies tend to have 3+ years next business day warranty on their Dell/HP laptops).

Comment: Shouldn't the company just give you a new laptop?

Comment: I think it depends on the machine's BIOS. I for example see in the BIOS boot from USB Network adapter on some machines and some other machines do not have this option

Answer (score 3):

It may or may not work.  Your computer is going to need to be able to boot from USB (of course) and the adapter in turn is going to have to be able to do a PXE boot or similar so that it can find its installation server and do its thing.  And, perhaps critically, as soon as Windows gets started (e.g. after it copies its installation files to your hard drive) it will need to be able to drive the network card, which may mean requiring a network driver for the adapter.  So, you might need to prep the install server with that driver.

There is a good outline [here](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-install-any-version-windows-other-network-computers) which is suitable for home LAN users and might give you some ideas on how best to proceed.

Finally, its worth pointing out that most modern laptops have a hidden reovery partition that can restore Windows to factory state without needing a network.  That may be an easier option if you can boot into it (eg via F8 or a BIOS option).